# SharePoint 2013 - how to add publishing pages library to root site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How can I add a publishing pages library to the root site of SharePoint 2013?  right now it looks like the root site is a wiki site with web part pages.

When I go to site contents, there is no folder for Pages.  And when I go to add an app, there is no option to add the Pages library.

Thanks for helping me grow/understand how I can modify SharePoint to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pages library is generated via Features, you need to enable the publishing infrastructure site collection feature and the site publishing feature in Site Settings.

Comment: So in "theory", I can do all this from the browser under site settings? or is there more to it in activating publishing features for the root directory? Thanks for the quick feedback!

Comment: You can do it from the UI, yes, assuming you are a site collection administrator.

Comment: I just checked and it is already activated...hmmm...

Comment: Both features are activated and nothing is there? You could try deactiving the site feature the the site collection feature, then activating the site collection feature and the site feature in hopes it reprovisions them.

Comment: It shouldn't, if the publishing features are active, it should have provisioned Pages, Site Collection Images, Site Collection Documents, Reuasable Content, Workflow Tasks, and Content and Structure Reports. Do any of these exist?

Comment: Yes, they all exist under site content, except for the Pages library (for publishing pages).  There is a "site pages" library, but that appears to only store wiki/webpart pages...

Comment: thank you PirateEric for providing me what I "should" be seeing.  I will research further on why my situation is unique...